# How to implement multi-branch regression trees in R

Tags: r, decision-tree

Is it possible to do the multi branch regression trees(non binary split) using R?

Answer (score 0):

A word on binary trees, contesting superiority of non-binary: [here](http://bus.utk.edu/stat/datamining/Tree%20Structured%20Data%20Analysis%20%28SPSS%29.pdf)

Tree models in R: [here](http://plantecology.syr.edu/fridley/bio793/cart.html)

R Party package for recursive partitioning: [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/party.pdf)

Comment: But the tree models link is showing all the binary tree models. Previously I used binary tree using rpart. But I need non binary tree for some specific requirements. It will be helpful if I can get some link/code on non binary tree using R